# php, I cant pass an array as reference

Tags: php, parameters, reference

this is the function:

```
public function func(&$parameters = array())
{
}
```

now I need to do this:

```
$x->func (get_defined_vars());
```

but that fails. Another way:

```
$x->func (&get_defined_vars());
```

it drops an error: Can't use function return value in write context in ...

Then how to do it?

Comment: You can't return an argument you've passed by reference, that's probably the error. Also, it should be `public function func(...` and not `public func function(...`. Give us the code for the whole method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_defined_vars()` returns an array, not a variable. As you can only pass variables by reference you need to write:

```
$definedVars = get_defined_vars();
func($definedVars);
```

Though I don't really see a reason to pass the array by reference here. (If you are doing this for performance, don't do it, as it won't help.)

Comment: yea, Im doing it for performance, no help? I thought a reference is less sized than arrays...

Comment: References in 99% of cases have nothing to do with size. It's just a way to pass a variable, so you can change it inside a function, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @user893856 PHP is smarter when you think in most cases. If you don't change the $array in the function it will never get copied. The reference might actually make the code slower ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
public  function func(&$parameters = array())
{
}
```

Not defined correctly.

Comment: ok, I was writing it from scratch, but that didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
call_user_func_array( 'func', $parameters );
```

See the notes on the [`call_user_func_array()` function documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) for more information.